# How to make RunBook recognize DateTime type?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, powershell-workflow

I am creating a Powershell workflow in Azure Automation.
When setting DateTime type `Set-AutomationVariable` with function,
Recognized as a string. Please let me know if you know how to solve it.

```
workflow variabletest{

     function Test-DateTime {
        $Now = Get-Date
       Set-AutomationVariable -Name 'VariableDateTime' -Value ($Now)
    }

     Test-DateTime

}
```

After execution, the value of the `'VariableDateTime'` confirmed from the Azure portal is as follows:

```
Name: VariableDateTime
Type: String
Value: 2019-12-12T06:35:23.208367+00:00
```

If there is `Set-AutomationVariable` outside the function, it has been confirmed that it becomes DateTime type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue, seems that it is by design of [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6) command.

See the [**Outputs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6#outputs):

> When a DateTime object is sent down the pipeline to a cmdlet such as Add-Content that expects string input, **PowerShell converts the object to a String object**.

Functions that need to be aware of the pipeline must be built with pipeline support.